# Anyone Have MediaRecorder Working with ParcelFileDescriptor.fromDatagramSocket?

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, file-descriptor

I am trying to work out an example of recording audio with `MediaRecorder`, which recorded data is passed through UDP socket on Android(>=4.0).

Reading an article:
[Broadcasting video with Android - without writing to local files](http://www.mattakis.com/blog/kisg/20090708/broadcasting-video-with-android-without-writing-to-the-file-system),
I employed [ParcelFileDescriptor.fromDatagramSocket](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor.html#fromDatagramSocket%28java.net.DatagramSocket%29)

Here is a simplified pseudocode I'm currently working on:

```
  //private DatagramSocket ds;
  //private MediaRecorder mRecorder;
  ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromDatagramSocket(ds);

  mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
  mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
  mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
  mRecorder.setOutputFile(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
  mRecorder.prepare();
  mRecorder.start();
```

Here is just a simple DatagramSocket(UDP) Listener thread loop to observe `DatagramSocket ds`

```
    //...
    private DatagramSocket ds;
    private int localPort = 39000;
    private MediaRecorder mRecorder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try
        {
            ds = new DatagramSocket(localPort);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        class IOThread extends Thread
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                byte []buf = new byte[1024];
                DatagramPacket packet= new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ds.receive(packet);
                        SocketAddress sockAddress = packet.getSocketAddress();
                        int len = packet.getLength();
                        String msg = new String(buf, 0, len);
                        System.out.println(msg + ":" + len + "byte receive by "+ sockAddress.toString());
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        IOThread io1 = new IOThread();
        io1.start();
    //..........
```

In principle, I expect recorded buffer by `MediaRecorder` is passed through the UDP FileDescriptor, and somehow I can manage the socket, but so far, I observe nothing happening.

I confirmed the UDP listener unit is working fine with other UDP input, and `MediaRecorder` unit should be fine since it works with localFiles not UDP socket FileDescriptor.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, it's best to pass MediaRecorder -> LocalSocket,

and here is my subsequent Q&A

[a LocalSocket (Unix domain) client-server data flow issue for MediaRecorder in Android (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072763/a-localsocket-unix-domain-client-server-data-flow-issue-for-mediarecorder-in-a)